# Reescrever URL no .htaccess para site com perfil

Tags: php, htaccess

Tudo bem?

Estou fazendo uma plataforma em PHP com perfil público. Precisaria que meu arquivo single.php fosse reescrito na URL sempre que alguém acesse por exemplo: meusite.com/fillipe ou meusite.com/luis.

Preciso pegar por GET toda informação depois da barra e reescrever na página toda vez que alguém acessar um perfil público diferente.

Alguém manja?

Comment: Provavelmente alguém manda, mas seria bom vc compartilhar conosco o que você já tentou fazer para que possamos te ajudar :)

Answer (score 0):

Então, você precisa adicionar o trecho abaixo no seu *.htaccess*, lembre-se de substituir o nome do arquivo e o nome do parâmetro. Faça um backup do arquivo *.htaccess* original, para caso der algum erro você tem como reverter.

Pesquise no google "URL amigáveis php htaccess" terá bastante vídeos e tutorias na internet.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)\/?$ perfi.php?idPerfil=$1 [NC,L]
```